# Simple, possibly one-liner tool to proxy http or https (SSLv2) to https (SSLv3)

Tags: ssl, https, proxy, sslv3

Quite often I have to access old sites using Sslv3 or other old, deprecated, SSL protocols.

Most of them are appliance that are not easy to update (storage controllers, tape controllers...).

Unluckily latest browsers on Linux (chrome and firefox) refuse to connect to this kind of sites, even with advanced options (SSLv3 support has been totally removed from Firefox).

What I need is a tool that can do such a thing:

`tool --listen HTTPS:9050 --connect HTTPS://oldsite:443/`

Obviously the "connect" part should accept any SSL version and the "listen" part should expose commonly accepted SSL versions.

I saw mitmtool and polipo but I could not configure them properly.
The key here is that the target site is not a proxy, but a simple https site.

Is it possible?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/405822/how-do-i-use-socat-as-a-proxy-server